# Typescript definition pattern for object with index

Tags: typescript

I have data that looks like this:

```
let equipment:Equipment =  {
  "1": {
    "name": "abc",
    "data": 123
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "def",
    "data": 234
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "ghi",
    "data": 345
  },
  ...
}
```

This would be easy to put in an array, but my equipment ID's start with 1 and I don't want to deal with the logic of excluding the [0] (which would be null) element.

Given this, I have come up with the following TypeScript Declaration Files.

```
interface Equipment 
{ 
  [ k: number ]: EquipmentBase;
}

interface EquipmentBase 
{
  name: string
  data: number
}
```

Further, when I return this equipment object with others I need to put it in a JSON object which requires yet another interface declaration.

```
interface EquipmentObj
{
  equipment: Equipment
}

/* returns {equipment: 
  {
  "1": {
    "name": "abc",
    "data": 123
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "def",
    "data": 234
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "ghi",
    "data": 345
  },
  ...
  }
}

*/
```

This feels like an excessive number of declarations (Equipment, EquipmentObj) just to declare an object that holds data.  Is there a different/better way to minimize the number of declarations that I am using?

Comment: "*I don't want to deal with the logic of excluding the [0]*" but with `{ [k: number] }` you have to deal with even more pathological cases like `[-123]` and `[0.5]` and `[NaN]`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I'm controlling all of the indexes so I don't really need to worry about stuff like that coming from other parts of my code.

Comment: Then why not just start your array indexes at 0? Surely using an idiomatic array is simpler than trying to come up with all these workarounds.

Comment: I'm controlling external equipment.  The external equipment has indexes that start at 1.  It would be more confusing in many other parts of my code to be storing/controlling/monitoring equipment[0] when it is really "equipment #1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you *can* do this:

```
interface EquipmentObj
{
  equipment: {
    [k: number]: {
      name: string
      data: number
    }
  }
}
```

But then, you can no longer declare anything as one of the inner types.

So if you need to type a variable, parameter, or return type as `Equipment` or `EquipmentBase`, then you could not fold that one in.

Comment: Thanks.  This does answer my question.  Seems a bit silly that I need to declare three interfaces of which 2 are very much like primitives.  But it is what it is.  I do have use cases for the different, specific types.